# Wait for an async method to return

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, xamarin, facebook-ios-sdk

I have a class:

```
public class User
{
    public string id, name, email, image;

    public User (IFBGraphUser user)
    {
        id = user.GetId ();
        name = user.GetName ();
        GetEmail ();
    }


    private void GetEmail()
    {
        FBRequestConnection.StartWithGraphPath ("/me", null, "GET", ConnectionReturn);
    }

    private void ConnectionReturn(FBRequestConnection connection, NSObject result, NSError error)
    {
        var me = (FBGraphObject)result;
        Console.WriteLine("this is a test");
        this.email = me["email"].ToString();
    }
}
```

With a async method: `StartWithGraphPath`

When the constructor is called I want to wait for `StartWithGraphPath` to finish before `GetEmail` returns.

**How Can I accomplish this?**

`StartWithGraphPath` does not return an `IAsyncResult` so I can't use `AsyncWaitHandle`.

**Edit**

When the code is called:

```
User u = new User(user);
Console.WriteLine("hello");
```

My application output:

```
hello
this is a test
```

Which is what leads me to believe `StartWithGraphPath` is being called async. Is there another explanation?

Whats odd is there is also a method called StartWithGraphPathAsync
So wouldn't this one Im using be synchronous by deduction?
It has a synchronous feel while in debugger but not when simply running the app

Comment: `StartWithGraphPath does not return an IAsyncResult` What does it return then?

Comment: @L.B: Nothing, it has a callback where it passes the result.

Comment: What does StartWithGraphPath do? Can you modify it?

Comment: Smells of a bad design. Can you not make `email` a property that exposes a `Task<string>`, and use a `TaskCompletionSource` to wire everything together? That way, if the consumer doesn't *need* the email (straight away) they're not left waiting, and if they do, they can compose on the `Task` using modern `async`/`await` forms.

Comment: OK, so you're using the Facebook SDK. You should have mentioned that (FBRequestConnection is from their SDK).

Comment: Also, looks like you're using Xamarin. Right?

Comment: @MarcelN. Sorry I should have you're right. Its late. Yes xamarin.

Comment: @MarcelN. This: http://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookios

Answer (score 2):

I *wouldn't* wait for it to complete in the constructor. Make the asynchrony visible (in a friendlier form) to the consuming code, and it can choose when or if to actually perform a wait for the email value:

```
public class User
{
    public string id, name, image;

    public User (IFBGraphUser user)
    {
        id = user.GetId ();
        name = user.GetName ();
        GetEmail ();
    }

    public Task<string> Email {
      get{
        return emailTask.Task;
      }
    }

    private TaskCompletionSource<string> emailTask =
         new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    private void GetEmail()
    {
        FBRequestConnection.StartWithGraphPath ("/me", null, "GET", ConnectionReturn);
    }

    private void ConnectionReturn(FBRequestConnection connection, NSObject result, NSError error)
    {
        var me = (FBGraphObject)result;
        Console.WriteLine("this is a test");
        emailTask.SetResult(me["email"].ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: I just edited my question a bit.. Not sure if StartWithGraphPath is really async or not now

Answer (score -1):

A quick solution would be to use a `ManualResetEvent` or [`ManualResetEventSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim(v=vs.110).aspx), wait for it in the constructor and set it in the callback method:

```
private readonly ManualResetEventSlim myEvent;

public User(IFBGraphUser user)
{
    myEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim();
    id = user.GetId();
    name = user.GetName();
    GetEmail();

    myEvent.Wait();
}

private void ConnectionReturn(FBRequestConnection connection, NSObject result, NSError error)
{
    var me = (FBGraphObject)result;
    Console.WriteLine("this is a test");
    this.email = me["email"].ToString();

    myEvent.Set();
}
```

**Please be aware** that this solution only works if the StartWithGraphPath method is not using the thread that was used to call it to invoke the callback. If it does - e.g. classes close to the user interface often will execute callbacks on the UI thread - then a deadlock will occur. (Thanks to @L.B for pointing this out)

If you can modify your class design I would suggest removing the expensive call from the constructor. Constructing an object should usually be cheap, and using an asynchronous method in it suggests that it might take some time.

Comment: I just edited my question a bit.. Not sure if `StartWithGraphPath` is really async or not now based off trying this answer.

Comment: @Deekor I just don't see why this would lock up the code forver, unless the call to Set is never executed.

Comment: any idea as to why my output is the way it is then?

Comment: @Deekor The call to StartWithGraphPath appears to be asynchronous. Why don't you simply use a debugger and set a breakpoint in the callback and constructor at the Wait and Set calls to see what happens.

Comment: it hits the wait. I click resume and it never hits the set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58761/discussion-between-dirk-and-deekor).

Comment: @Dirk you block the UI thread. `StartWithGraphPath` might be trying to call the callback function in UI context. Since it is blocked, callback will never be executed. A classical deadlock problem...

Comment: @L.B True, this could happen as I don't know that API at all. Thanks for pointing this out and I'll add some information about it in my answer.